Getting child venvs that can access parent venv libs
I have created a venv with all libraries for all my python devloppements. Let's call it the parent venv.
Then i create a venv per project. Let's call these venvs the children venv.
Is there a way to "hack" the --system-site-packages option to get my children venvs get access to the parent venv libraries ?
I tried to modify the home variable in pyvenv.cfg... But it doesn't work.
NB: I would like to avoid to use the shell variable PYTHONPATH

Not that I know of. You can maybe try your luck with a .pth file in the child venv to point to the parent venv. See site documentation. Otherwise yes, you're left with modifying PYTHONPATH or sys.path.
